# Android Runtime Error on recyclerview setHasFixedSize(boolean)

Tags: android, firebase

When I update the data with the Toggle button, it causes this error. Can you look where the problem is? With Toggle button, I want to make the data in the 0-states-001 table to true or false. Just toggle button code does not work everything else works

Error code: android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(boolean)' on a null object reference

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3d0iI.png)
[application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auzZs.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="stechome.berkeylen.firebasedatabase.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
     ProductsAdapter adapter;
        List<Product> productList;
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            setContentView(R.layout.product_layout);

            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


            productList = new ArrayList<>();


            DatabaseReference dbProducts = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("0").child("titles");

            dbProducts.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                        for(DataSnapshot productSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                            Product p = productSnapshot.getValue(Product.class);
                            productList.add(p);
                        }



                        adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });




            ToggleButton simpleSwitchBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleData);



            simpleSwitchBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

                    DatabaseReference ref = mDatabase.child("0").child("states").child("001");
                    Map<String, Object> newStatus = new HashMap<>();
                    newStatus.put("true", isChecked);

                    ref.setValue(newStatus);
                }
            });

public class Product1 extends Product {


    private boolean states;

    public Product1(){

    }

    public Product1(boolean states) {

        this.states = states;
    }


    public boolean getStates() {
        return states;
    }

}

public class ProductsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductsAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Product product = productList.get(position);

        // holder.textViewID.setText(String.valueOf(product.getid()));
       //holder.viewStatus.setText(String.valueOf(product.getStates()));
       // System.out.println("111111111231312312312312312312"+product.getStates());

        holder.textViewTime.setText(product.gettime());
        holder.textTitle.setText(String.valueOf(product.gettitle()));
        holder.textviewPlaces.setText(String.valueOf(product.getplaces()));
//        holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(mCtx.getResources().getDrawable(product.getImage(), null));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

    class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textViewID, textViewTime, textTitle, textviewPlaces;
        ToggleButton viewStatus;
        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            viewStatus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.toggleData);
            textViewTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.time_textView);
            textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_textView);
            textviewPlaces = itemView.findViewById(R.id.places_textView);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the `activity_main` .XML file.

Comment: add activity_main, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in with your Recyler View. Because Your Recycler View is null. That is why you are getting null pointer exception. The problem lies in your this code

```
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.product_layout);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

In your code, you are calling setContentView() 2 times. And most probably in **product_layout** You don't have that actual recycler view. And this is causing **Null Pointer Exception**.